# Attribute selectors not working with webpack in production

Tags: webpack, sass

I am using attribute class selector in scss and it works fine in development mode. However in production no styling applied.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    //....
    [class^='someName'] {
    //...
    }
}
```

I have descendant classes starting with someName that gets their styling applied only in dev environment with webpack. Any ideas how to configure webpack to get this working. P.S. I use modules, so names of classes changed to unique. Could be issue here?

Comment: What's the actual CSS being applied on dev and on prod? Does the Inspector show any differences?

Comment: On dev element {margin-top: 10px } is applied. This is the styling I pass [class^='someName'] selector. On prod element has empty styling element {}.

Comment: So in the compiled CSS, the definition is completely missing? How do the environment definitions differ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the cause of this, but I found an alternative. I was using a `localIdentName` setting in `css-loader` for css modules. This kind of code can't be altered by the css modules pattern (can't add a prefix and suffix) and even though it exists in a `.modules.scss` file, it should be probably be passed to another loader. There are probably more settings that can accomplish this without another package, but here is the before and after:

```
  // css loader options
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]', // tells the pattern for the css classnames, makes them like this parentModule_currentModule_randomNumbersAndLetters
          },
          sourceMap: true,
          esModule: false,
          importLoaders: 2
        },
      },
      'resolve-url-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

and I changed that to:

```
  // top of file
  const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');

  // css loader options
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
          },
          sourceMap: true,
          esModule: false,
          importLoaders: 2
        },
      },
      'resolve-url-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```